# Identify game with ~30 pegs and 30 holes

Tags: identify-this-game

Found 2 boxes with content shown below and wondered if it is a game and what is named? The boxes contained no rules but had a certain "homemade" feel about it why the option of it being a game is not ruled out by missing rules.

Content in each box:

- 2 boards with 3 x 5 holes each
- 32/31 pegs (one box contains 32, the other 31), one end is rounded and one is flat

[image: Found boxes]

Edit: Picture of pegs in holes [image: Pegs in holes]

Comment: My initial thought is [peg solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire) but it looks like an abnormal layout for that type of game.

Comment: Interestingly, there are more total pegs (32) than slots (30). There also isn't an easy way to clearly identify players, assuming that this is a multiplayer game. Do the holes punch all the way through the boards? And why do you say there are "32/31" pegs - what's up with the 32nd? For now, I'd say chances are that it's some kind of craftmanship helper tool rather than a game, but it certainly looks game-ish.

Comment: Could we get some photos with the pegs in the holes? Would be interesting to see how far they poke out.

Comment: @Malco Agree. The layout doesn't seem quite right but is interesting. Regarding photos: I am not currently at the same place as the boxes, but will post additional photos in about 12 hours. :)

Comment: @TheThirdMan I edited the question to clarify that the boxes contain a different number of pegs. That it is a craftmanship helper tool is a good lead even if I would prefer it to be a game :)

Comment: I noticed that each peg has a flat end and a rounded end. That suggests that one player has flats and other rounded ends and that the game would seem to allow flipping the peg somehow.

Comment: Dara would fit. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34319/dara But no idea why board would be in two parts. Box seems big enough to hold board in one piece.

Comment: @MaxW: Seems good enough to post as an answer. It fits very well, and if it's a selfmade game (the box isn't of a great size for either the board or pegs, so that's not a long shot), maybe its creator had those half-board-sized pieces of wood around and decided just to go with it. Maybe the boxes are also not the original packaging.

Comment: @MaxW Sounds plausible! As TheThirdMan says it is very likely selfmade, which could explain the split board. If you make an answer out of your comment you can get some rep ;)

Comment: Are you sure this is a game? It looks like a child's toy. I have something like it at home and it's just for the toddlers to push pegs in holes...

Comment: @Erik I am not sure it is a game, I wrote so in the post. The finding place makes it plausible that it is a game or some sort of tool as TheThirdMan suggested. That it is a child's toy for pushing pegs is very unlikely, given the finding place, but you couldn't know that so thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dara would fit. You'd only need 12 pegs each. Extra could be just in case you lost some. From [Board Game Geek-Dara](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34319/dara):

> *A game from Nigeria that may be played by two players or teams. Traditionally the game was played on an area consisting of 5x6 spaces using sticks or stones for pieces.*
>
> *The game begins with the players taking alternating turns placing one of their twelves pieces in an empty space. Once all of the pieces have been placed, the players alternate moving one of their pieces into an adjacent empty space. Diagonal movement is not allowed.*
>
> *When a player moves a piece to cause three of their pieces to be in a row, that player may remove one opposing piece that is not part of a row of three such pieces. Players are not permitted to make a move which results in more than three of their pieces being in a row. A player wins the game when the opposing player is unable to make a a row of three pieces.*

Comment: I don't know if this is a good fit, there isn't any distinction between pieces. How can you tell which piece belongs to which player?

Comment: @Malco - All the pegs are flat on one end and round on the other. So one player has flat ends and the other round ends.

Comment: @ MaxW I think that the rounding is to make the pegs go into the holes easier, not to differentiate players. I think either @Erik's idea that it is a children's toy, or perhaps it is a single player game is more plausible.

Comment: It makes sense to me - the board is not one solid piece because that could be unwieldy to remove from the box. Nothing is colored, so a simple rounding of the edges can differentiate between players. The bevel around the holes is sufficient to aide in placing the pegs.

Comment: I agree with @Malco, one rounded end doesn't seem sufficient to distinguish sides. One *could* use those pieces to play this game, but it doesn't seem like that was it's design.